# Jest unable to parse inline types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, vite

I have a very simple react project that is being scaffolded and for some reason, while vite builds and serves the app just fine. Jest seems to be having a strange typescript issue where it does not recognize inline types for anonymous functions. This is a big issue with React as this feature is quite important for `useCallback` hooks.

Here is the example code:

```js
const onChange = useCallback((event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  setDarkMode(event.currentTarget.checked);
}, [setDarkMode])
```

Jest fails to compile this with the following error:

```
 FAIL  src/App.test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run
    SyntaxError: /home/menachem/dev/tabletop/packages/web/src/components/layout/Header.tsx: Unexpected token, expected "," (11:37)
       9 |   const {darkMode, setDarkMode} = useContext(DarkModeContext);
      10 |
    > 11 |   const onChange = useCallback((event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
         |                                      ^
      12 |     setDarkMode(event.currentTarget.checked);
      13 |   }, [setDarkMode])
      14 |
      2 |
      3 | import { Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
    > 4 | import Header from './components/layout/Header'
        | ^
      5 | import Sidebar from './components/layout/Sidebar'
      6 |
      7 | function App() {
```

Has anyone seen this before?

Here is the full stack-trace if it helps. You can also find the source code on GitHub at https://github.com/mhornbacher/tabletop

```
      at constructor (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parse-error.ts:81:19)
      at JSXParserMixin.toParseError [as raise] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/tokenizer/index.ts:1487:19)
      at JSXParserMixin.raise [as unexpected] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/tokenizer/index.ts:1528:16)
      at JSXParserMixin.unexpected [as expect] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/util.ts:149:28)
      at JSXParserMixin.expect [as parseParenAndDistinguishExpression] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:1784:14)
      at JSXParserMixin.parseParenAndDistinguishExpression (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:1170:21)
      at JSXParserMixin.parseExprAtom (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/plugins/jsx/index.ts:574:22)
      at JSXParserMixin.parseExprAtom [as parseExprSubscripts] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:710:23)
      at JSXParserMixin.parseExprSubscripts [as parseUpdate] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:687:21)
      at JSXParserMixin.parseUpdate [as parseMaybeUnary] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:649:23)
      at JSXParserMixin.parseMaybeUnary [as parseMaybeUnaryOrPrivate] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:387:14)
      at JSXParserMixin.parseMaybeUnaryOrPrivate [as parseExprOps] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:399:23)
      at JSXParserMixin.parseExprOps [as parseMaybeConditional] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:354:23)
      at JSXParserMixin.parseMaybeConditional [as parseMaybeAssign] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:294:21)
      at parseMaybeAssign (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:248:12)
      at JSXParserMixin.callback [as allowInAnd] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:3142:12)
      at JSXParserMixin.allowInAnd [as parseMaybeAssignAllowIn] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:247:17)
      at JSXParserMixin.parseMaybeAssignAllowIn [as parseExprListItem] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:2755:18)
      at JSXParserMixin.parseExprListItem [as parseCallExpressionArguments] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:1044:14)
      at JSXParserMixin.parseCallExpressionArguments [as parseCoverCallAndAsyncArrowHead] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:886:29)
      at JSXParserMixin.parseCoverCallAndAsyncArrowHead [as parseSubscript] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:775:19)
      at JSXParserMixin.parseSubscript [as parseSubscripts] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:731:19)
      at JSXParserMixin.parseSubscripts [as parseExprSubscripts] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:716:17)
      at JSXParserMixin.parseExprSubscripts [as parseUpdate] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:687:21)
      at JSXParserMixin.parseUpdate [as parseMaybeUnary] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:649:23)
      at JSXParserMixin.parseMaybeUnary [as parseMaybeUnaryOrPrivate] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:387:14)
      at JSXParserMixin.parseMaybeUnaryOrPrivate [as parseExprOps] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:399:23)
      at JSXParserMixin.parseExprOps [as parseMaybeConditional] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:354:23)
      at JSXParserMixin.parseMaybeConditional [as parseMaybeAssign] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:294:21)
      at parseMaybeAssign (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:248:12)
      at JSXParserMixin.callback [as allowInAnd] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:3137:16)
      at JSXParserMixin.allowInAnd [as parseMaybeAssignAllowIn] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:247:17)
      at JSXParserMixin.parseMaybeAssignAllowIn [as parseVar] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:1540:16)
      at JSXParserMixin.parseVar [as parseVarStatement] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:1201:10)
      at JSXParserMixin.parseVarStatement [as parseStatementContent] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:554:21)
      at JSXParserMixin.parseStatementContent [as parseStatementLike] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:417:17)
      at JSXParserMixin.parseStatementLike [as parseStatementListItem] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:366:17)
      at JSXParserMixin.parseStatementListItem [as parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:1395:16)
      at JSXParserMixin.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody [as parseBlockBody] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:1368:10)
      at JSXParserMixin.parseBlockBody [as parseBlock] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:1336:10)
      at JSXParserMixin.parseBlock [as parseFunctionBody] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:2589:24)
      at JSXParserMixin.parseFunctionBody [as parseFunctionBodyAndFinish] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:2560:10)
      at parseFunctionBodyAndFinish (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:1633:12)
      at JSXParserMixin.callback [as withSmartMixTopicForbiddingContext] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.ts:3116:14)
      at JSXParserMixin.withSmartMixTopicForbiddingContext [as parseFunction] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:1631:10)
      at JSXParserMixin.parseFunction [as parseExportDefaultExpression] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:2519:19)
      at JSXParserMixin.parseExportDefaultExpression [as parseExport] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:2414:25)
      at JSXParserMixin.parseExport [as parseStatementContent] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:597:25)
      at JSXParserMixin.parseStatementContent [as parseStatementLike] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:417:17)
      at JSXParserMixin.parseStatementLike [as parseModuleItem] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:354:17)
      at JSXParserMixin.parseModuleItem [as parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:1394:16)
      at JSXParserMixin.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody [as parseBlockBody] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:1368:10)
      at JSXParserMixin.parseBlockBody [as parseProgram] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:213:10)
      at JSXParserMixin.parseProgram [as parseTopLevel] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.ts:195:25)
      at JSXParserMixin.parseTopLevel [as parse] (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/index.ts:45:10)
      at parse (../../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/index.ts:66:38)
      at parser (../../node_modules/@babel/core/src/parser/index.ts:28:19)
          at parser.next (<anonymous>)
      at normalizeFile (../../node_modules/@babel/core/src/transformation/normalize-file.ts:50:24)
          at normalizeFile.next (<anonymous>)
      at run (../../node_modules/@babel/core/src/transformation/index.ts:39:36)
          at run.next (<anonymous>)
      at transform (../../node_modules/@babel/core/src/transform.ts:29:20)
          at transform.next (<anonymous>)
      at evaluateSync (../../node_modules/gensync/index.js:251:28)
      at sync (../../node_modules/gensync/index.js:89:14)
      at fn (../../node_modules/@babel/core/src/errors/rewrite-stack-trace.ts:99:14)
      at transformSync (../../node_modules/@babel/core/src/transform.ts:66:52)
      at ScriptTransformer.transformSource (../../node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:545:31)
      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (../../node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:674:40)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (../../node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:726:19)
      at Object.require (src/App.tsx:4:1)
      at Object.require (src/App.test.tsx:2:1)
```

Comment: Your question "Has anyone seen this before?" can be definitively answered "yes" or "no" and possibly even with supporting evidence.  I'm confident that's not what you actually want answered.  Please edit your question so that you can get an answer that would be useful to you.

Comment: well i cloned your repo and i just changed to `<Navbar.Heading><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faDAndD} /> TableTop</Navbar.Heading>` and all tests are passed